# github pr comment with multiline string

Tags: bash, github-api

I tried to do the following using the github API but I got the error `https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx/pull/45162 accepts at most 1 arg(s), received 4`. Not sure if this is a bash error or if its a API error.

```
body_comment=":rocket:[infra-apply-terraform]   
\`\`\`                                            
DIRS=app/models/
FLAVORS=staging,prod
\`\`\`"
gh pr comment --body $body_comment
```

Comment: Change that to `"$body_comment"`?

Comment: Using a tool like Shellcheck (https://www.shellcheck.net/) will help point out why.